# two plane curves intersecting in a single point

Tags: curves, algebraic-curves, plane-curves

do there exist plane curves $f,g\in\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]_d,\ d\ge 2$ that intersect in exactly one point in $\mathbb{P}^2$? Taking both to be products of $d$ distinct lines obviously works, but I cant come up with anything else.

I feel like this should just be obvious whether it exists or not.

Thx for any help

Comment: What exactly here is $\mathbb P^2$? The real projective plane?

Comment: No, the projective space over $\mathbb{C}$, not just over the reals.

Comment: You may want to add that to your post because it is not clear from context.

Comment: Doesnt Bezouts theorem tell you there isn't any?

Comment: I dont think so. Bezout tells us that the sum of the intersection multiplicities is $d^2$. So one single point with multiplicity $d^2$ should be possible by Bezout. And taking $f=\prod l_i, g=\prod l_i'$ gives an example if the lines are all distinct. Or is there another way to use Bezout that I miss?

Answer (score -1):

Of course they do exist. Consider, for instance, the curves $f=x^d+yz^{d-1}$ and $g=x^d+yz^{d-1}+z^d$.